# Angularjs step by step form

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to create exactly same form given in this fiddle
 [steb by step angular form](http://fiddle.jshell.net/glenn_antoine/rNudn/)

but whenever i click on the next button data entered in the first step resets.. how can i prevent this? On submit all data is undefined while reading in javascript.

Please help me..

Comment: Post one question per question, and post all the relevant code. A plunkr reproducing the problem is also welcome.

Comment: Provide your own code so we can see where the issue is. But as a suggestion check that all the form data is connected to the same `scope` meaning its all being handled by a single controller. Store all the data in an object within the scope like so `ng-model="user.name"` etc. So that in the end all the form data is in the `user` object.

Comment: I am trying to run same example given in the link... after filling the step 1 form if i click on next step it goes to step 2 but if i want to do any changes in previous step... after click on previous button whatever data was entered earlier should be retained but all fields are empty..

Comment: @yog see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JsFiddle code you provided you are not retaining the users data, meaning that data is being **Binded** to anything in the controller. So when leave the section the data is removed.

To retain data make the following changes:

```
// In your controller add the following object to the $scope
   $scope.user = {}

// In your HTML code add the following to your input fields
   <input type="text" id="teamName" ng-model="user.teamName" placeholder="Team Name" />
```

**Notice the `ng-model` tag in the `input` field this is what binds your data to the user object within your controller**

Heres a working [JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rNudn/145/), please note that I only updated the **Team Name** field. Type something in the Team Name field and go to the next section and it will retain your data. You will need to update the remaining fields.